/usr/bin/ld multiple definition of during compile
I just want to mention that I didnt write this code or modify it in any way prior to trying to compile it. I have just been copying the source from EL5 to 6 to 7 and compiling it. I think when it went from EL5 to EL6 I had to change some MySQL library references but I didnt change anything in the code this time.
I am attempting to compile an old program that was released around 2007 on AlmaLinux 9. To this point I have been able to keep this thing running through all of the OS upgrades but this time it's been a nightmare.
Whenever I try to compile this code I get these messages:
>/bin/sh ../libtool    --mode=link gcc  -g -O2 -rpath '/usr/local/plot/lib' -L/usr/lib64 -L >-L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib64  -o poll snmp.o dbi.o poll.o util.o targ.o gram.o >hash.o  -lnetsnmp -lgd -lpng -lltdl -lz -lrt -lpthread -lm 

(I'm not wholly certain why it has "-L/usr/lib64" 4x on that previous line.)
>mkdir .libs
>gcc -g -O2 -o poll snmp.o dbi.o poll.o util.o targ.o gram.o hash.o  -L/usr/lib64 ->L/home/zct/build/src -lnetsnmp -lgd -lpng -lltdl -lz -lrt -lpthread -lm -Wl,--rpath ->Wl,/usr/local/plot/lib
>/usr/bin/ld: dbi.o:/home/zct/build/src/dbi.h:28: multiple definition of `db_test'; >snmp.o:/home/zct/build/src/dbi.h:28: first defined here
>/usr/bin/ld: dbi.o:/home/zct/build/src/dbi.h:29: multiple definition of `db_status'; >snmp.o:/home/zct/build/src/dbi.h:29: first defined here
>/usr/bin/ld: dbi.o:/home/zct/build/src/dbi.h:36: multiple definition of `db_connect'; >snmp.o:/home/zct/build/src/dbi.h:36: first defined here
>/usr/bin/ld: dbi.o:/home/zct/build/src/dbi.h:37: multiple definition of `db_disconnect'; >snmp.o:/home/zct/build/src/dbi.h:37: first defined here
>/usr/bin/ld: dbi.o:/home/zct/build/src/dbi.h:38: multiple definition of `db_commit'; >snmp.o:/home/zct/build/src/dbi.h:38: first defined here
>/usr/bin/ld: dbi.o:/home/zct/build/src/dbi.h:39: multiple definition of `db_insert'; >snmp.o:/home/zct/build/src/dbi.h:39: first defined here
>/usr/bin/ld: dbi.o:/home/zct/build/src/dbi.h:30: multiple definition of `db_populate'; >snmp.o:/home/zct/build/src/dbi.h:30: first defined here
>/usr/bin/ld: dbi.o:/home/zct/build/src/dbi.h:32: multiple definition of `db_intSpeed'; >snmp.o:/home/zct/build/src/dbi.h:32: first defined here
>/usr/bin/ld: dbi.o:/home/zct/build/src/plot.h:154: multiple definition of `std_colors'; >snmp.o:/home/zct/build/src/plot.h:154: first defined here
>collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

and this ultimate output:
make[1]: *** [Makefile:528: poll] Error 1

Here are lines 526-528 of Makefile:
poll$(EXEEXT): $(poll_OBJECTS) $(poll_DEPENDENCIES) $(EXTRA_poll_DEPENDENCIES) 
        @rm -f poll$(EXEEXT)
        $(AM_V_CCLD)$(poll_LINK) $(poll_OBJECTS) $(poll_LDADD) $(LIBS)

make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/zct/build/src'
make: *** [Makefile:395: all] Error 2

Here are the lines
394-395:
all: $(BUILT_SOURCES)
        $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) all-am

I can't tell if the ld messages are the reason the compilation is stopping or if those are just informational/warning messages.
Literally any nudge in the right direction is appreciated. I've fixed quite a few oddities to get to this point so far. Thank you.
The answer was -fcommon in the CFLAGS as pointed out by John Bollinger below.

Could you please show us lines 20 through 40 of dbi.h? I'm pretty sure I know what's wrong, but I need to see the code to know how to fix it.

You're defining these functions in multiple source files.

Maybe you have the function definitions in a .h file instead of .c, and you didn't declare them inline.

This issue commonly arises with headers that provide external variable definitions (as opposed to merely declarations).  That produces a definition of each such variable in every translation unit that includes the header.  C forbids multiple definitions of the same variable in the same program, but some compilers accept that by default, as an extension.  Older GCC does that.  Newer GCC does not.  You can get newer GCC to exhibit the old behavior by compiling with -fcommon.

@JohnBollinger From the names, these mostly look like functions, not variables.

Likely duplicate of this, this, this, this, and more I cannot fit in a comment.

@JohnBollinger: Re “C forbids multiple definitions of the same variable in the same program”: No, it does not. It permits multiple external definitions in different translation units and does not specify the resulting behavior.

Would close as a duplicate if OP provided sufficient information to confirm this is a duplicate. Since information is lacking, I voted to close as needs debugging information.

Thank you, @EricPostpischil.  Yes, I know that my wording was imprecise, and I think you know that I know. I also think that the difference is likely irrelevant to the OP, and that the words I chose will be more accessible to them.

@Barmar, the same applies to functions, of course, except that -fcommon probably doesn't rescue that. But I would be much more surprised to find external functions defined in a (C) header than to find variables with function-like names, and the diagnostics do seem to indicate that the multiple definitions are originating from a header.

@ZCT: you say you "fixed quite a few oddities".  Is there any chance that that included removing some appearances of the static keyword from dbi.h?

I didnt modify the code or write it. I just copjed the src from the EL7 host to the EL9 host and tried to compile it.

[Edit] your question and provide a [mcve].  Without one, all anybody can do is guess.

The answer ended up being -fcommon posted by John Bollinger but I don't know how to accept it as an answer. Thank you.
